# c++ declare vector array to get a class, but cannot access member variable

Tags: c++

When I declare vector to get a class, but cannot access member variable.

Code has more details,

```
class test{
  public :
    int num;        //member variable
    test(int k){    //constructor
      num=k;
    }
};

int main(){
  vector<test *> a[10];  //declare vector 
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     a.push_back(new test(p));  //use constructor initial
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     cout<<a[i].num<<endl;  //THIS STEP ERROR, 'NO MENBER num'
}
```

I can't find out solution. QAQ~

Comment: You might want to take a look at ctor-init-list.

Comment: `a.push_back(new test(p));` cannot compile either since `a` is not a `vector`.

Comment: `a` is an array of vectors, but you're treating it like a vector.

Comment: `vector<test> a; for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a.push_back(test(p));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class test{
  public :
    int num;        //member variable
    test(int k){    //constructor
      num=k;
    }
```

Why not a `struct` if all members are public anyway?
Also, that ctor calls for a ctor-init-list, like this, instead:

```
struct test{
    int num;
    test(int num) : num(num) {}
```

```
};

int main(){
  vector<test *> a[10];  //declare vector
```

Lies in advertising, you are actually defining, and an array of ten vectors.

```
  vector<test*> a; // This is a vector of pointers to test
```

```
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     a.push_back(new test(p));  //use constructor initial
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     cout<<a[i].num<<endl;  //THIS STEP ERROR, 'NO MENBER num'
}
```

`a[i]` is of type `test*`, and pointers do not have members. You wanted to use the arrow-operator `->`.

```
     cout<<a[i]->num<<endl;
```

Last, you forgot to delete all that memory you allocated.

Solutions:

1. Don't allocate dynamic memory but store `test`-objects directly.

   ```
   vector<test> a; // This is a vector of test
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       a.push_back(test(p));  //use constructor initial
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       cout<<a[i].num<<endl;
   ```
2. Use smart-pointers (`<memory>`):

   ```
   vector<std::unique_ptr<test>> a; // This is a vector of std::unique_ptr<test>
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       a.push_back(new test(p));  //use constructor initial
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       cout<<a[i]->num<<endl;
   ```
3. Add all the manual memory-management, but remember all allocations can throw.
   Too long and error-prone, won't write it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array of vectors:
  std::vector<> a[10];
An array of 10 vectors.

Each slot in the array is a vector of *pointers* to your test class:

```
  std::vector<Test *> a[10];
```

So, to access a `Test` item, you will need to find out which array element to access and where the item is inside the array:

```
  Test p_object = 0;
  p_object = a[3].[2]; // The fourth vector, the third slot in the fourth vector.
  std::cout << "Test item from 3rd slot in 4th vector: "
            << p_object->num
            << "\n";
```

I don't think this is what you need or want.  The picture that the code shows resembles a 2d matrix.   Usually, 2d Matrices are declared as a vector of vectors or a 2d array; not a combination of both.